# rgba doesn't work for fill property in CSS

Tags: css, svg, rgb

```css
circle {
    fill: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<svg width='400' height='400'>
    <circle r='100' cx='200' cy='200'></circle>
</svg>
```

rgb code works for this, but I found rgba doesn't work. The shapes become invisible.
I tested this on Chrome and Firefox.

Am I missing something else here?

Comment: it works for me but your circle is so pale against a white background, it's basically invisible.

Comment: In your case the color is a very light grey - almost white. This is why it _seam_  it doesn't to work. If you change the color to something else like `fill: rgba(248, 0, 0, 0.5);` you'll see it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle is almost white and also partially transparent, you just can't see it against a white background.

On a black background you can see it's rendered perfectly OK by both Firefox and Chrome...

```css
svg {
    background-color: black;
}

circle {
    fill: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<svg width='400' height='400'>
    <circle r='100' cx='200' cy='200'></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! dang! I was so stupid ! lol thanks!